# Nodes & Complete isolation from internet

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to have a cluster with N nodes in a complete isolation from Internet and instruct kubelet to download image from a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> instruct kubelet to download image from a proxy

It's not that you need to teach kubelet anything about proxies, you just need to configure the [docker daemon environment](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy) and it should work, or `rkt` if you are using it.